# How to chose the bounds of an integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, transformation

How to evaluate the integral $$\int_{-1}^1 \int_0 ^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x^2(x^2+y^2)^2dydx$$ via polar coordinates?

I substituted $x^2+y^2$ by $r^2(\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\phi))$ and so on but how to chose the bounds of integration?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the $x$ limits, for what value of $\theta$ gives $x= \pm 1$? On the %y% limits, what happens when to $\theta$ when $y=0$? If $x=r \sin \theta$ what is the value of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of integration is the upper semi-circle.

\begin{align*}
  \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} x^2(x^2+y^2)^2 \,dy \,dx &=
  \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{1} (r^2 \cos^2 \theta)(r^4)\, r\, dr \, d\theta \\
  &= \left( \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos^2 \theta \, d\theta \right)
     \left(\int_{0}^{1} r^7 dr \right) \\
  &= \frac{\pi}{2} \times \frac{1}{8} \\
  &= \frac{\pi}{16}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The set described by the aboves is $\{x^2 + y^2 \le 1, y\ge 0 \}$

Obviously this is a filled half unit circle above the x-axis… is that clear to you?

So: $0 \le r \le 1, \phi \in [0,\pi]$.